# Pygame tetris block not moving down at certain condition

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

I'm making tetris in Pygame but in pieces of only 1 block (not 4).
Here is the block class :

```
# Creating a matrix representing the grid 
environment = numpy.zeros((21, 16), dtype=numpy.int32)

class Block(object) :
    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y, self.color, self.row, self.column = 643, -32, 0, 0, 7
        self.img, self.mv_step = myblock, 32
        pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT+1, 800)
        self.is_current_block = True
    
    def blit_and_manage(self):
        MyScreen.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))
        # this makes the first 2 lines not count, this helps the player at the end of the game ...
        if self.y == 40:
            self.row = 0
        # handling events
        for e in events:
            # moving a block to the left
            if ((e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT) and self.x != 407) and self.is_current_block and environment[self.row, self.column-1] == 0:
                self.x -= 32
                self.column -= 1
                environment[self.row, self.column+1] = 0
            # moving a block to the right
            elif ((e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT) and self.x != 887) and self.is_current_block and environment[self.row, self.column+1] == 0:
                self.x += 32
                self.column += 1
                environment[self.row, self.column-1] = 0
            # moving a block down
            if ((e.type == USEREVENT+1) or ((e.type == KEYDOWN and (e.key == K_DOWN)) and self.is_current_block) and environment[self.row+1, self.column] == 0:
                self.y += self.mv_step
                if self.y > 40:
                    self.row += 1
                    environment[self.row-1, self.column] = 0
        # creating boundaries for the blocks
        if self.y >= 672:
            self.y = 672
            self.is_current_block = False
        # adding the block's color to the matrix in its corresponding position
        if self.y > 3:
            environment[self.row, self.column] = self.color
        # preventing blocks from moving down if there is another block underneath
        if self.row != 20 and environment[self.row+1, self.column] != 0:
            self.is_current_block = False
```

The bug is: when filling a horizontal line (by spamming the K_s or K_DOWN), blocks will stand on each other until there are only two spaces left, the next block that will spawn won't move down even that the space underneath it is empty and then the game will become unresponsive until I do a keyboard interrupt with ctrl + c.
(this happens only in the middle line)
[image: figure]

Here is the matrix when the bug happens :
(assuming that the grid is not 21 by 16 as in the example code above, just to not make the post longer)

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: You should shorten your question @Developeeer. You should follow the advice of Prune. So, someone actually reads your question.

Comment: @Prune, done, I made my question shorter

Comment: btw if you want to try my code, just create a large display , get any image representing a block, then copy the ``Block()`` class and run it

Comment: Please don't tag us for individual updates.
When you complete the MRE, we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if this is your actual problem (if not, please leave a more detailed description of what you want to achieve) but here is the solution for what i think is your problem:

in the conditional statement for moving the block down you check:

```py
if ... and environment[self.row+1, self.column] == 0:
```

when initializing `self.row = 0` so `self.row+1` will be 1 and `environment[self.row+1, ...]` will go to the 2nd row of `environment` (python has zero-based indexes)
below:

```py
self.y += self.mv_step  # self.mv_step = 32
if self.y > 40:
    self.row += 1
```

this means that the `self.row` value will not increment until `self.y` is > 40 (before `self.y` just stays at `0`) which is in the third (visual) row the case (before it is only -32, 0 or 32).
so when the block finally reaches the 3rd (visual) row the `self.row` value is 1.
the block will therefore modify:

```py
environment[self.row, self.column] = self.color
```

(in this case `environment[1, ...]`)
this means that `environment[1, ...]` - the row the block will check in it's original position - is modified by the (visually) 3rd row of blocks.

**solution**
if you still want 1 row of free space at the top, simply change the if condition for incrementing the row count to:

```py
if self.y > 0:  # instead of > 40
    self.row += 1
```

if you want no space at the top just remove this (the above mentioned) condition.
edit: i added a `try` - `except IndexError` statement around the moving down block.

Comment: Thank you so much ! You deserve those 50 bounties. My code was really messy that I couldn't find the reason of that issue. I had put that ``if self.y > 40:`` because if the block is in the first row, it can't set the index of the previous row to zero as there is no one (in the virtual grid) , and I should have put this condition just before the line containing ``environment[self.row-1, self.column] = 0`` and not before increamenting the row count. I appreciate your help !

Comment: @Developeer i'm glad i could help.  the next time you ask something please add the full code required to understand the program - in this case the main loop and the constants/imports. i pretty much had to guess those; having those informations immediately would have made it a bit easier.

Comment: @Developeeer PS: I think you still have to manually award the bounty. (i haven't received anything yet)